# format value stored in plain text as money using value_format

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to modify a php wp plugin to format the output $value as money using  valuemoney_format('%i', $value) . "\n";

I've tried

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB');
function format_value_money($value){
return valuemoney_format('%i', $value) . "\n";
}
```

and

```
$atts['placeholder'] = valuemoney_format('%i', $value) . "\n";
```

and also

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap %1$s"><input id="%5$s" oninput="output%5$s.value=%5$s.value" %2$s />%3$s</span><output class="contactform7-output" name="%1$s" id="output%5$s" for="%5$s">'%i'%4$s . "\n"</output>
```

the value is formated as plain text (10000) and would like to show the value with currency format (£1,000) or (GBP 1,000)

```
<?php
    function wpcf7_range_slider_extender_handler ( $tag ) {
        $tag = new WPCF7_FormTag( $tag );
        if ( empty( $tag->name ) ) {
            return '';
        }
        $validation_error = wpcf7_get_validation_error( $tag->name );
        $class = wpcf7_form_controls_class( $tag->type );
        $class .= ' wpcf7-validates-as-number';
        if ( $validation_error ) {
            $class .= ' wpcf7-not-valid';
        }
        $atts = array();
        $atts['class'] = $tag->get_class_option( $class );
        $atts['id'] = $tag->get_id_option();
        $atts['tabindex'] = $tag->get_option( 'tabindex', 'int', true );
        $atts['min'] = $tag->get_option( 'min', 'signed_int', true );
        $atts['max'] = $tag->get_option( 'max', 'signed_int', true );
        $atts['step'] = $tag->get_option( 'step', 'int', true );
        if ( $tag->has_option( 'readonly' ) ) {
            $atts['readonly'] = 'readonly';
        }
        if ( $tag->is_required() ) {
            $atts['aria-required'] = 'true';
        }
        $atts['aria-invalid'] = $validation_error ? 'true' : 'false';
        $value = (string) reset( $tag->values );
        if ( $tag->has_option( 'placeholder' ) || $tag->has_option( 'watermark' ) ) {
            $atts['placeholder'] = $value;
            $value = '';
        }
        $value = $tag->get_default_option( $value );
        $value = wpcf7_get_hangover( $tag->name, $value );
        $atts['value'] = $value;
        if ( wpcf7_support_html5() ) {
            $atts['type'] = $tag->basetype;
        } else {
            $atts['type'] = 'text';
        }
        $atts['name'] = $tag->name;
        $atts = wpcf7_format_atts( $atts );

        $html = sprintf(
            '<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap %1$s"><input id="%5$s" oninput="output%5$s.value=%5$s.value" %2$s />%3$s</span><output class="contactform7-output" name="%1$s" id="output%5$s" for="%5$s">%4$s</output>',
            sanitize_html_class( $tag->name ), $atts, $validation_error, $value,  sanitize_tag_name( $tag->name ));
        return $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are virtually already there.  Two things come to mind:

Firstly: I don't know if wordpress defines `valuemoney_format`, the default php-provided function is [`money_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php).
Secondly: you have to make sure that the locale you want to set via `set_locale` is defined on the machine.  You can check that with executing `locale -a | grep LOCALE` in a terminal and checking the output list.

In my case, `en_GB` is /not/ defined, but `en_GB.utf8` is.

Example `psysh`-Session:

```
>>> function format_value_money($value){
        return money_format('%i', $value) . "\n";
    }
>>> setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB');
=> false
>>> setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB.utf8');
=> "en_GB.utf8"
>>> format_value_money(1000);
=> "GBP1,000.00\n"
```

Check for the locale:

```
❯ locale -a | grep en_GB
en_GB.utf8
```

Further question: Are you sure about `%i`?  That's the international format, resulting in the GBP prefix in the example above.  If you use `%n` instead, the in the UK more accepted and expected `"£1,000.00\n"` would be the formatted value.

Addendum: If you need to create a locale, this is how:

```
> sudo locale-gen en_GB
> sudo update-locale
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @tomregner! , yes I'd like to use %n but when I try it doesn't work got � instead of £ Also thanks for giving me the right function, now the variable prints in the correct format for the placeholder but on the dynamic value by modifying this line 
`sanitize_html_class( $tag->name ), $atts, $validation_error, money_format('%i', $value) . "\n", sanitize_tag_name( $tag->name )); 
return $html; `
not very skilled on PHP as you can see :b. 
I'll keep trying

Comment: The missing pound symbol is an encoding issue: If you deliver the webpage with UTF8-encoding, make sure that you use an UTF8 locale.  Also: I simply assumed a linux server wrt the locale handling.  If this solved your issue feel free to upvote/accept ;-)

Comment: Yes sorry forgot to replace en_GB.utf8, Thanks!